# How do I mock a function that is imported separately from others and return a preferred JSON in JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mocking, sinon-chai

I have a set of functions that are exported from a utils.js file , and used in one of the rest api route function, I am trying to test the function by mocking the return value , but I am unable to do so.

```
// utils.js
exports.callSeparate = function() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
        return {x:10, y:10}
    }
}

exports.callSeparate = function() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
        return {x:11, y:12}
    }
}


// index.js
const {callSeparate} = import("../utils.js")

router.post(firstfunction,secondfunction,thridfunction);

async function secondfunction(req, res, next) {
    result = await callSeparate()
    return result;
}


//test.js
let callAPistub = sinon.stub(utils,'callSeparate');
callAPistub.returns(    
    {x:13, y:14}
    );
```

I am able to mock the function if I import the entire utils library and then use that function in the rest API.

```
// index.js
const utils = import("../utils.js")

router.post(firstfunction,secondfunction,thridfunction);

async function secondfunction(req, res, next) {
    result = await utils.callSeparate()
    return result;
}
```

How can I mock the function when its written as stated in the first code block, this is not my code ,I am trying to test it so my hands are little tied. I have read about rewire and proxyquire but they are very confusing and I am unable to achieve the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your doesn't quite make sense. `callAPistub.returns( returns {x:13, y:14} )` isn't really a function, so it shouldn't return anything. You are just setting the return value, so when that function is now called, it will return {x:13, y:14}.

I got this to work:

```
//test.js
  const utils = require("./utils.js")
  var sinon = require('sinon');
  let callAPistub = sinon.stub(utils,'callSeparate1');
  callAPistub.returns( {x:13, y:14} );
  console.log(callAPistub())
```

Terminal:

```
node test.js
{ x: 13, y: 14 }
```

Notice that I changed `callAPistub.returns` to this:

```
callAPistub.returns({x:13, y:14});
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have fixed the statement to callAPistub.returns({x:13, y:14} ). The code that you have added works only if "const {callSeparate} = import("../utils.js")" this line is replaced with "const utils = import("../utils.js")" and this line "result = await callSeparate()" is replaced with this "result = await utils.callSeparate() "